temp index create error when running HANA subquery?
I wrote an AMDP method, and when I run the method, I get the following DUMP.

Error while executing a database procedure

During execution of database procedure

ZCL_MM_REPORTE_INV_AMDP=\>GET_MERGED_DATA

an error occurred.

SQL code of the database: 2048

Database Procedure (AMDP) Information
    Full error message from the database:
    column store error:
    "SAPHANADB"."ZCL_MM_REPORTE_INV_AMDP=>GET_MERGED_DATA#stb2#20240605161919": line 8 col 3 (at
    pos 273): "SAPHANADB"."ZCL_MM_REPORTE_INV_AMDP=>GET_MERGED_DATA": line 18 col 5 (at pos
    657), "SAPHANADB"."ZCL_MM_REPORTE_INV_AMDP=>GET_MERGED_DATA": line 9 col 5 (at pos 338),
    "SAPHANADB"."ZCL_MM_REPORTE_INV_AMDP=>GET_MERGED_DATA#stb2#20240605161919": line 7 col 3 (at
    pos 170): temp index create error: [2040023] Check stack size for 61440 bytes failed, only
    59904 bytes left

    Active calls in the database:
  1 ZCL_MM_REPORTE_INV_AMDP=>GET_MERGED_DATA: line 18 col 5 (AMDP Method)
      ZCL_MM_REPORTE_INV_AMDP=>GET_MERGED_DATA: line 9 col 5 (inlined) (AMDP Method)
      ZCL_MM_REPORTE_INV_AMDP=>GET_MERGED_DATA#stb2#20240605161919: line 7 col 3 (inlined) (AMDP M
  2 ZCL_MM_REPORTE_INV_AMDP=>GET_MERGED_DATA#stb2#20240605161919: line 8 col 3 (AMDP Method)

    Datatbase Connection Used:
    <default>


However, if I place a breakpoint on the line where the execution fails, and then press F8 to let the process continue, the DUMP does not occur. Here is the relevant part of the code:
  METHOD get_merged_data BY DATABASE PROCEDURE FOR HDB LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT OPTIONS READ-ONLY.


    lt_keys = select distinct bukrs  ,
                              zeinr,
                              ambito_valoracion,
                              tipo_material,
                              material,
                              descripcion,
                              umb
              from :it_source;

    et_merged = select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY k.material) AS numero_linea,
                       k.bukrs,
                       k.zeinr,
                       k.ambito_valoracion,
                       k.tipo_material,
                       k.material,
                       k.descripcion,
                       k.umb,
                       (select ifnull(periodo_ant_canti, 0)    from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as periodo_ant_canti,
                       (select ifnull(periodo_ant_valor, 0)    from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as periodo_ant_valor,

                       (select ifnull(recep_compras_canti, 0)  from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as recep_compras_canti_01,
                       (select ifnull(recep_compras_valor, 0)  from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as recep_compras_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(produ_termin_canti, 0)   from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as produ_termin_canti_01,
                       (select ifnull(produc_termi_valor, 0)   from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as produc_termi_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(cons_mater_cantid, 0)    from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as cons_mater_cantid_01,
                       (select ifnull(cons_mater_valor, 0)     from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as cons_mater_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(cons_maqui_cantidad, 0)  from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as cons_maqui_cantidad_01,
                       (select ifnull(cons_maqui_valor, 0)     from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as cons_maqui_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(cons_inter_cantid, 0)    from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as cons_inter_cantid_01,
                       (select ifnull(cons_inter_valor, 0)     from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as cons_inter_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(trans_canti, 0)          from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as trans_canti_01,
                       (select ifnull(trans_valor, 0)          from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as trans_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(trans_pla_canti, 0)      from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as trans_pla_canti_01,
                       (select ifnull(trans_pla_valor, 0)      from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as trans_pla_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(ventas_canti, 0)         from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as ventas_canti_01,
                       (select ifnull(venta_valor, 0)          from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as venta_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(ajus_invent_cant, 0)     from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as ajus_invent_cant_01,
                       (select ifnull(ajus_invent_valor, 0)    from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as ajus_invent_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(recep_maqui_cant, 0)     from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as recep_maqui_cant_01,
                       (select ifnull(recep_maqui_valor, 0)    from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as recep_maqui_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(tras_maqui_cant, 0)      from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as tras_maqui_cant_01,
                       (select ifnull(tras_maqui_valor, 0)     from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as tras_maqui_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(recep_sincosto_cant, 0)  from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as recep_sincosto_cant_01,
                       (select ifnull(recep_sincosto_valor, 0) from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as recep_sincosto_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(recep_variac_cant, 0)    from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as recep_variac_cant_01,
                       (select ifnull(recep_variac_valor, 0)   from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as recep_variac_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(varia_cantidad, 0)       from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as varia_cantidad_01,
                       (select ifnull(variaci_valor, 0)        from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as variaci_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(inv_final_cantid , 0)    from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as inv_final_cantid_01,
                       (select ifnull(inv_final_cantidv, 0)    from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as inv_final_cantid_v01,
                       (select ifnull(inv_final_valor , 0)     from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as inv_final_valor_01,
                       (select ifnull(inv_final_valorv, 0)     from :it_source as _01 where _01.merge_ctrl = '01' and _01.material = k.material and _01.ambito_valoracion = k.ambito_valoracion) as inv_final_valor_v01,
                       '' as merge_ctrl_01,

-- The pattern above repeats 12 times with different merge_ctrl values (from '01' to '12')

                from :lt_keys as k;

  ENDMETHOD.

In this method, I'm trying to merge data from it_source into et_merged with several subqueries to fetch specific values for each material and valuation area. The DUMP occurs unless I step through the code with a debugger. I suspect the issue might be related to how the subqueries are handled. Any insights or help would be appreciated.
Additional Context:
The it_source table contains data to be merged based on various conditions.
The et_merged table is the output where the merged results are stored.
The method uses SQLScript for data processing in SAP HANA.
Observed Behavior:
When running the method without debugging, it results in a DUMP.
Placing a breakpoint and stepping through the code prevents the DUMP from occurring.
Request for Help:
I suspect the issue might be related to how the subqueries are handled.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help.
I searched a lot and found nothing.

The error message temp index create error: [2040023] Check stack size for 61440 bytes failed, only 59904 bytes left indicates that HANA didn't have enough available memory to create an intermediate result set when the procedure runs outside debugging mode. Note, debugging mode will call the procedure with less data - which likely allows it to work correctly. Looking at the SQL code posted, I recommend to redesign this to avoid the window-clauses and the scalar-subqueries.
